# If the type attribute in <button> tag is missing then will that button created with <button> tag behave like a submit button?

Tags: javascript, html, button, submit

Suppose, I have following HTML code :

```
<button>Click Me!</button>
```

In above code I have not used the attribute **'type'**.

So, in this case will this button behave like a Submit Button which will submit all the form data to the server?

If yes, then can I execute JavaScript code on the onclick event of above button which is missing the **'type'** attribute?

If no, what exactly will happen?

Thanks.

Comment: why was this down voted this is a legitimate question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a button to behave like just a button, then yes, your markup needs to be:

```
<button type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

In this case, you can easily add a `click event` with:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].addEventListener('click',myFunction,false);
```

---

**N.B.** If you don't mark up the button properly (ie. you omit the `type` attribute) and the browser then treats it like a `input type="submit"`, you can *still* add a `submit event`:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].addEventListener('submit',myFunction,false);
```

Comment: *"If you don't mark up the button properly..."* `type` is optional. `<button>foo</button>` is entirely "proper" if you want a submit button.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the default `type` for `button` is `submit`; as is [documented in the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-button-type).

> So, in this case will this button behave like a Submit Button which will submit all the form data to the server?

Yes, it will.

> If yes, then can I execute JavaScript code on the onclick event of above button which is missing the 'type' attribute?

Yes, of course you can, just like any other button. The click handler will run before the form is submitted.

Comment: Can I execute the code <button onclick="some_javascript_ code"></button> on the above button that misses 'type' attribute?

Comment: You would (arguably) be better off deploying the `onsubmit` event.

Comment: @user2839497: As I said above: Yes. There are use cases for hooking `click` on a submit button. But note that that handler will only run if the button is clicked; there are other ways for forms to get submitted. If you *just* want form submission behavior, use the form's `submit` event instead. But if you're looking for the button click, yes, you can do that.